# RewriteRule to add string to end of URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is not working for me:

```
RewriteRule ^tags/[^?/] Templates/showpage.asp?DBID=1&LNGID=2&TMID=133&FID=898&tag=%1 [QSA]
```

When I go to page `www.mydomain.com/tags/tag1`, it rewrites it to `www.mydomain.com/Templates/showpage.asp?DBID=1&LNGID=2&TMID=133&FID=898&tag=`.

How do I add "tag1" to the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No experience with ISAPI, but I would probably try this:

```
RewriteRule ^tags/(\w+)/?$ Templates/showpage.asp?DBID=1&LNGID=2&TMID=133&FID=898&tag=$1 [QSA]
```

Essentially, what you're missing is the brackets to capture the matching tag that is to be used in place of `$1`

I placed the conditional slash (`/?`) outside the bracket with the assumption that tags shouldn't contain the slash but URLs with or without the trailing slash are acceptable.

#### Update

If you need to be more liberal with what characters you accept as tags, you can use something like `^tags/([^/?]+)/?$` to allow all characters (apart from slash and question mark) as suggested by [Pavel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204916/isapi-rewrite-problem/4204942#4204942).

Comment: i tried this RewriteRule ^tags/([\U+0590-\U+05FFA-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ Templates/showpage.asp?DBID=1&LNGID=2&TMID=133&FID=898&tag=$1 [QSA]
it's working for english and digits but for hebrew it's rewrite it without the $1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^tags/([^?/]+) Templates/showpage.asp?DBID=1&LNGID=2&TMID=133&FID=898&tag=%1 [QSA]
```